# how to save dynamic game data without being saved in /data/pkg-name/

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to save my user and game data without being saved in /data/pkg-name/.
I searched for it a lot but I couldn't find the way.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where do you think it should be saved? `Application.persistentDataPath` is almost always the right place to put it.

Comment: but I see a lot of games that they don't saved their data in that place .

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean in android devices. In that case you could simply use something like this:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath;
// Output-> Internal Storage/Android/data/com.company.pkg

int x = path.IndexOf("Android", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);

path = path.Substring(0, x);
// Output-> Internal Storage/
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I said without being saved in  /data/pkg-name/